# spread operator not working in javascript object notation

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am learning to use es6 in one of my react project and apply new spread operator **`...`**  this is working fine when using array `[]` ( as spread operator) syntax but failed when using inside object  `{}` ( as rest properties) i.e. not assigning value just modifying.

Are these both are two completely different things?  here are my system detail

- node v 6.11.4
- babel-core v 6.26.0
- macOS Sierra v 10.12.6
- Sublime Text 3 build 3143

---

```
/*eslint no-unused-vars:0 */

let alpha = ['a','b','c', {first: 'first'}];
let beta = ['be', 'ta', { first: 'second'}];

let more = {text:'more', date: new Date()};

const gamma = [...alpha, more]; // this is working fine 

console.log(gamma, alpha);

let todos = [{id: 1, completed: false}, {id:2, completed: true}];

const noCurlyFatArrow = () => {
                            return todos.map(todo =>
                                (todo.id === action.index)
                                ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed }
                                : todo
                            )
                    };
noCurlyFatArrow();
```

---

and run the JS Build System in the sublime text (`⌘ + B`) and it gives following error in the console

```
  /opt/rqt/src/react-only/spread.js:1

  ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed }  

     ^^^ 

  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Also made few changes in *.babelrc* filr from this [issue dicussion](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170) but no luck.

#### .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3", "react"], //
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

tried without "stage" and with `"stage-0"` as well.

#### **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rqt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Using rest/spread in *object literals* is not valid ES6 syntax

Comment: but react guys are using in [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/reducers/todos.js)

Comment: but react guys are using their own babel preset, not ES6

Comment: @Bergi they're using the transform-object-rest-spread plugin, I don't think that's what the problem is here.

Comment: I have already installed `transform-object-rest-spread` plugin and added in .babelrc  but its not working.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196)

Comment: Thank you for valuable link @FelixKling I was also confused what to call. now get some understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by doing various plugin installation but here is the summary

1. create new sublime text 3 build system for es6 with following code

   ```
    {
      "cmd": ["/Users/keshav.m/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/babel-node $file"],
      "shell": true,
      "selector": "*.js"
   }
   ```

Note: I have installed node using `nvm` , so set complete path ( someone please tell how to add path without using complete path in sublime) of babel-node

2. installed `babel-preset-es2015` globally and locally too

   ```
   npm install --save-dev -g babel-preset-es2015
   ```

Note: during installation, npm warn

> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:  Thanks for using
>   Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read
>   babeljs.io/env to update!

( this is really frustrating thing by node and don't know how it affect)

3. also run `nvm alias default node` do not know whether it helps or not.
4. now select this build system and run the code. it works fine now.
5. update *.babelrc* file

   ```
     {
       "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
       "plugins": ["transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
     }
   ```
6. updated *package.json* file

   ```
    {
     "name": "rqt",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "jquery": "^3.2.1",
       "react": "^16.0.0",
       "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
       "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
       "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
       "redux": "^3.7.2"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
       "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
       "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
       "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
       "eslint": "^4.10.0",
       "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.0.0",
       "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
       "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.39.1",
       "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
       "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
       "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
       "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0"
     }
   }
   ```

note: also install `"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y"` , it was asking for peer dependency.

hope it help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm run start` from the command line in the project root directory. I don't think sublime is transpiling your code.